# Why won't eclipse run my php file?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm running eclipse galileo (5.5) with PDT 2.1.2. I have "PHP Executables" pointed to /usr/bin/php, which outputs:

```
$:/usr/bin$ php -version
PHP 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2009 19:14:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
```

I have created a new PHP project with a very basic php file named "newfile.php":

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

When I right click the file and select "Run As->PHP Script", absolutely nothing happens! I expect the Console to gain focus and show my output, but . . . nothing! No output in the console, no error . . . nada.

I think I've got eclipse pointed to the correct php file. So, what am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Eclipse PDT ships broken, as far as I can tell, and no one wants to admit it!

Comment: As far as I remember the console in Eclipse/PDT is broken. It omits many parts of the output and if you have just very less to output, nothing remains to display. Update: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282997 . I didnt found a solution either...

Answer (score 2):

From you console, I see that you have php installed from Zend Engine product.
You need to configure PHP executables in Window->Preferences->PHP->PHP Executables.
Difine right path of php and php.ini files in the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but try putting the shebang line in at the top of your file. Proper shell scripting dictates that it needs to be there, and eclipse/pdt might care.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
//.....rest of your file
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities:

-make sure the file has focus in the editor when 'run as'

-check project specific settings

Answer (score 0):

Also try to right-click not a file in a file structure tree, but the very source code of this file and select the same.

Answer (score 0):

try running as web page, since if you have php it implies you have apache, so eclipse will only open the url for you